# How to generate SSL certificate on windows machine for use with IIS?

Tags: iis, lets-encrypt, certbot

I come from Linux background and have previously hosted websites on nginx. I use certbot to create and install SSL certificate.

I'm trying my hands-on Windows IIS, I have deployed a website on IIS. Now to add a SSL to my website I'm trying to use certbot. However their website https://certbot.eff.org/ doesn't have any instructions for IIS.

How to generate SSL certificate on windows machine for use with IIS?

Comment: Have you looked this up? https://www.google.com/search?q=certbot+iis

Comment: You should rephrase your question as how to enroll Let's Encrypt certificates (not any other certificate, as your use of certbot implicitly sets a restriction) to an IIS site, and then I believe any search engine will give you tons of useful results.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is probably to setup a tool like Certify the Web, which is a Windows tool that does very similar things as certbot does but comes with a GUI and can import the generated certificate directly into the IIS cert store and thus makes certificate installation and renewal a very easy job. It can be downloaded for free from their website: https://certifytheweb.com/

Comment: Given the context of the question, posting an answer with a recommendation to use an third-party resource is probably the best advice.

Comment: I agree, we use that on our IIS servers and it works very well and is quite straightforward to setup and use, especially if you're already familiar with the concepts from another platform.